# Subviews added with storyboard over hand-added subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a little issue about subviews with x-code with storyboards.

I want to do a little application with balls. You have to click on them and they simply disappear.
I also wanted to have a pause menu.

So i made a viewController with 1 view (the general view), 1 subview (the pause menu), made with the storyboard (so i don't see them in the code)

I wanted to had a EAGLView in this viewController so i did this:

```
self.director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
self.myglView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 420)
                                pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                depthFormat:0       
                         preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                 sharegroup:nil
                              multiSampling:NO
                            numberOfSamples:0                   ];
}

[self.director setOpenGLView:self.myglView];

glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

self.myglView.opaque = NO;
self.myglView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.myglView];
```

I added some body(balls) in the 2D world created in this eaglview, this is working but now when i want to put the game on pause.

I make "pop" the pause menu with this:

```
self.pauseView.hidden = false;
```

the pause menu appear but all the balls are ON the pause menu :/

Someone see what my issue is ? ^^'
Is there something like layers or priority subviews ?

Thanks a lot for reading and helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your pauseView in the storyboard,  then it will be added when your view is loaded, which is before you actually add your EAGLView. Adding subviews is just like stacking Legos onto each other. The last one added, is in the top.

You should be able to add your EAGLView underneath your pauseview like this:

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.myglView belowSubview:self.pauseView];
```